# indexeddb on IOS devices

Tags: ios, indexeddb

I have a problem with an indexeddb query with index when running on IOS devices.

```
$.indexedDB(dbName).objectStore(tablename).index("INDICE").each(function(itemLocal) {
       itemLocal.delete();
}, [VALORINDICE]).then(function() {
                    callback();
                }, function() {
                    console.log("error");
                });
```

The problem is if there is more than one record that matches the index, it does not eliminate them, it eliminates the first one and leaves. But if for example I put console.log (itemLocal) instead of itemLocal.delete() if it shows all those that match the index. Any suggestions of something that may be leaking?

I have tried with this code and I get the same error(code without api jquery)

```
var request = indexedDB.open(DATABASE_NAME);
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  var db = request.result;
  var transaction = db.transaction(["TABLE"], "readwrite");
  var table = transaction.objectStore("TABLE");
  var index = table.index("INDEX");
  var req = index.openCursor();
  req.onsuccess = function() {
    var cursor = req.result;
    if (cursor) {
        console.info(cursor.value);
        cursor["delete"]();
        cursor["continue"]();
    }
  };

  req.onerror = function(e) {
    console.error(e, req);
  };
};

request.onerror = function(e) {
  console.error(e, request);
};
```

Comment: What API are you using to interact with indexedDB? It seems like either the API is incorrect or you are using the API incorrectly.

Comment: i use a Jquery Plugin for the IndexedDB API (Jquery-IndexedDB) but i can assure you that it is not due to improper use because it works correctly on android and windows since 4 years ago

Comment: Have you tested whether the error occurs when not using the Jquery-IndexedDB API? It is difficult to help when it may be a problem with the API, or with Safari's implementation of indexedDB.

Comment: ok, today I'll do some tests. thank you

Comment: @Josh, I´ve done the tests and realized that the queries in iOS without that API still not working, and I have the same issue. I spend hours and hours to resolve this bug but cant find the solution. Any ideas about the reason?

Comment: the issue is in the interpretation that makes IOS. do you  know how can I do a massive delete for iOS? thank @Josh

Comment: Can you please share the code you used that did not involve using the jquery API and instead interacted with indexedDB directly?

Comment: I added the code without api in the header @Josh

Comment: Thanks! The code looks good to me, so I don't think it is a syntax error. Maybe Safari has bad implementation of IDBCursor.prototype.delete, at least on an index instead of an object store. Try instead to load all items into array first using openCursor, then iterate over array and issue separate deletes. The logic will be the same but it avoids using the cursor delete method.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do some tests.